# Elastix 4 and MariaDB 5.5.50: Can't replicate foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, mariadb, elastix

I have been have ripping my hair out for the past week trying to get back my Foreign Key constraints on my *contact* table in Elastix.

The constraints I am trying to replicate are the following:
[Replicate these foreign keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxd8x.png)

I have tried:

`ALTER TABLE contact ADD CONSTRAINT (`id_agent`) REFERENCES agent(id);`

but to no avail. I get the response:

```
 SQL query: ALTER TABLE call_entry ADD CONSTRAINT call_entry_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY(id_contact) REFERENCES contact.id MySQL said: #1005 - Can't create table 'call_center.#sql-888_37e3e' (errno: 150)
```

All the databases agent,queue_call_entry,campaign_entry exist and have data. The structure of the contact table is here:
[contact table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wShUg.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: "but to no avail" is not a very good description of the problem you're having. What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Are there any error messages that could help others pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @kristaps I would query this:
ALTER TABLE call_entry ADD CONSTRAINT call_entry_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_agent) REFERENCES `agent`.`id`;
and get this in return:
#1005 - Can't create table 'call_center.#sql-888_37d8c'

Comment: @P.Salmon already been through there mate. It is not very specific for adding foreign keys to table already in use.

Comment: So I tried this based off the mysql documentation

ALTER TABLE call_entry ADD CONSTRAINT call_entry_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY(id_contact) REFERENCES contact.id;

And I get:

SQL query:

ALTER TABLE call_entry ADD CONSTRAINT call_entry_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY(id_contact) REFERENCES contact.id

MySQL said: 
#1005 - Can't create table 'call_center.#sql-888_37e3e' (errno: 150)

Comment: Please add table schemas (show create table <tablename> and sample data.

Comment: @P.Salmon Elastix creates the db's mate. I will scratch around the source to find the .php (if I am lucky) file responsible for the creation.